# .htaccess не пускает

Tags: ubuntu, .htaccess, apache2

На серваке прописан виртуальный хост, в папке лежит файл .htaccess   надо разрешить доступ только для ip сети 192.168.20.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.20.
```

Comment: судя по всему, в качестве *http*-сервера используется *apache*. какой версии — 2.4 или ниже?

Comment: 192.168.20.0/24

Comment: require ip 192.16.20.0/24